# How do you add a delete button to python calculator?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help adding a delete button to a python calculator. I have tried the other methods suggested on the site and they haven't worked. I would be very grateful if you could help me as I would like to know how to do this for future projects.  Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import*



def btnClick(numbers):
    global operator
    operator=operator + str(numbers)
    text_Input.set(operator)

def btnClearDisplay() :
    global operator
    operator=""
    text_Input.set("")

def btnEqualsInput():
    global operator
    sumup=str(eval(operator))
    text_Input.set(sumup)
    operator=""

def backspace(self):
#check if all has been removed
#make sure you import the re module
    if re.match(r'\d$', self.current):
        self.display(0)
        self.new_num = True
    else:
        self.current = self.current[:-1]    
        self.display(self.current)

cal = Tk()
cal.title("Calculator")
operator=""
text_Input =StringVar()

txtDisplay = Entry(cal,font=('arial black', 20,'bold') , textvariable=text_Input, bd=30, insertwidth=6,
bg="powder blue", justify='right').grid(columnspan=6)

btn1=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="1",command=lambda:btnClick(1), bg="powder blue",).grid(row=1,column=0)

btn2=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="2",command=lambda:btnClick(2), bg="powder blue").grid(row=1,column=1)

btn3=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="3",command=lambda:btnClick(3), bg="powder blue").grid(row=1,column=2)

Addition=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="+",command=lambda:btnClick("+"), bg="powder blue").grid(row=1,column=3)
#===================================================================================

btn4=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="4",command=lambda:btnClick(4), bg="powder blue").grid(row=2,column=0)

btn5=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="5",command=lambda:btnClick(5), bg="powder blue").grid(row=2,column=1)

btn6=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,
            text="6",command=lambda:btnClick(6), bg="powder blue").grid(row=2,column=2)

Subtraction=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="-",command=lambda:btnClick("-"), bg="powder blue").grid(row=2,column=3)

#===================================================================================

btn7=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="7",command=lambda:btnClick(7), bg="powder blue").grid(row=3,column=0)

btn8=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="8",command=lambda:btnClick(8), bg="powder blue").grid(row=3,column=1)

btn9=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="9",command=lambda:btnClick(9), bg="powder blue").grid(row=3,column=2)

Multiplication=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="x",command=lambda:btnClick("x"), bg="powder blue").grid(row=3,column=3)

#===================================================================================

Clear=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="CE",command= btnClearDisplay, bg="powder blue").grid(row=4,column=0)

btn0=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="0",command=lambda:btnClick(0), bg="powder blue").grid(row=4,column=1)

EQUALS=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="=",command=btnEqualsInput, bg="powder blue").grid(row=4,column=3)

Division=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="Ã·",command=lambda:btnClick("Ã·"), bg="powder blue").grid(row=4,column=2)

#===================================================================================

Delete=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="Ã·",command=lambda:btnClick("Ã·"), bg="powder blue").grid(row=4,column=2)

cal.mainloop()
```

Thank you. If you could help me, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: What's the specific problem? It appears you already know how to add buttons to a calculator.

Answer (score 1):

Here`s function of Delete button:

```
def btnDelete():
    global operator
    operator=operator[:-1]
    text_Input.set(operator)
```

And change your

`Delete=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="Ã·",command=lambda:btnClick("Ã·"), bg="powder blue").grid(row=4,column=2)` 
to

`Delete=Button(cal,padx=16,bd=8, fg="black",font=('arial black', 20,'bold'),
            text="Delete",command=btnDelete, bg="powder blue").grid(row=4,column=2)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. However, when I put this in, my lambda command could no longer recognize the standard division symbol (line and two dots). Do you know how to fix this?